# Zoom that follows mouse

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React Component that zooms an image and the zoomed image follows the mouse.

I've created a pen to show what I've done so far: [React Zoom](https://codepen.io/LeoNero/pen/VWKeYZ)

And here is the code:

```
class ProductGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      imgZoomed: false,
      mouseX: undefined,
      mouseY: undefined
    }

    this.zoomImage = this.zoomImage.bind(this)
    this.unZoomImage = this.unZoomImage.bind(this)
    this.moveMouseImg = this.moveMouseImg.bind(this)
  }

  zoomImage () {
    this.setState({
      imgZoomed: true
    })
  }

  unZoomImage () {
    this.setState({
      imgZoomed: false
    })
  }

  moveMouseImg (e) {
    const {
      top: offsetTop,
      left: offsetLeft
    } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()

    const x = ((e.pageX - offsetLeft) / e.target.width) * 100
    const y = ((e.pageY - offsetTop) / e.target.height) * 100

    this.setState({
      mouseX: x,
      mouseY: y
    })
  }

  render () {
    const transform = {
      transformOrigin: `${this.state.mouseX}% ${this.state.mouseY}%`
    }

    const classes = Object.assign({}, transform, {
      transform: this.state.imgZoomed ? 'scale(2.0)' : 'scale(1.0)',
      maxHeight: '615px',
      maxWidth:  '100%',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      transition: 'transform .1s ease-out'
    })

    const divStyles = {
      height: '615px',
      width:  '615px',
      float: 'left',
      marginLeft: '10px',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      borderStyle: 'solid'
    }

    return (
      <div style={divStyles}>
        <img
     src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/maxresdefault_8yZPhSS.jpg"
          style={classes}
          alt="dmsak"
          onMouseOver={this.zoomImage}
          onMouseOut={this.unZoomImage}
          onMouseMove={this.moveMouseImg}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<ProductGallery />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The problem is that when I move the mouse, the component just starts to "shake"! I am using a scale of 2.0, but if I change it to 1.5 (`transform: scale(1.5)`), the problem only happens in the edges of the image.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is that scale adjusting the entire size of the image? It should be scaling only the background-image. I think your bounds are scaling with your zoom-event; which is confusing the hell out of your mouse-coordinates listeners.

Comment: Also, this is completely awesome. nice work :)

Comment: Thanks! Well, I did not understand your point... I'm not using a background-image

Comment: What I mean is... When the size/scale of the image is increased, the y/x coordinates of the cursor are also changed. Say the cursor is at 10y/10x on a 50x50 grid... Then the scale function changes the proportions of that grid. That changes the coordinates of the cursor, relative to the grid it's being mapped to. You're listening to where the cursor is, to tell the image where to be, but you're also telling the image to get bigger when the mouse is over it, which changes where the mouse is, over-top of the image.

Comment: So the solution, would be to have one *(invisible) element with a fixed-size that the mouse hovers over, and controls if the image is zoomed / where the image is... And another element, behind the invisible element, which contains the image and can be stretched and repositioned _separately_ from the invisible element, which is tracking where the mouse is.

Comment: To demonstrate this idea, try drawing a smiley face inside a 10x10 grid on graph paper... then place a red X on it. Now, draw the same smiley-face at 20x20... Where will you place the X?

Comment: Moving some, or all of these: `onMouseOver={this.zoomImage}
          onMouseOut={this.unZoomImage}
          onMouseMove={this.moveMouseImg}` on to the container-div, should help.

Comment: Got it and everything makes sense! Well, about your last comment, I moved some props to the container-div, but nothing worked...

Comment: Oh wait... I've change my pen (I forgot to add some things haha) and I moved the props to the container-div. If I use 1.5 scale, it does not get crazy when I move the mouse to the edges... but if I use a 2.0 scale, the image disappears :P @admcfajn

Comment: Another problem is that there are some white borders, because the scaled image does not occupy all the space in the div

Comment: Well, I also added a background-image instead of using <img />, and it is now working. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice job! You're very welcome. Glad you got it sorted out :)